# JavaScript цикл выборки массива for( let x of y)

Tags: javascript

Можно ли в конструкции `for(let x of y)` задать двойную выборку типа `for(let x of y && let k of i)`?

Comment: Так нет нельзя...  Можно один цикл вложить в другой...

Comment: так и предполагал. думал сократить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью одного `for(var x of y)` это не получится, но с помощью одного классического `for(;;)` такое можно запросто сделать:

```js
var y = [3, 5, 7],
 i = [6, 8, 9];

for(var x = 0, k = 0; x < y.length; x++, k++)
 console.log('y[' + x + '] = ' + y[x] + ', i['+k+'] = ' + i[k]);
```

Массивы в этом случае могут быть разной длины.